# PFQuery includeKey not loading full object

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery

I have an `Activity` object that has a pointer to a `User` object under the column "createdBy".

My query goes like this:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
[query includeKey:@"createdBy"];
```

Now when I print out the `Activity` object fetched, the key "createdBy" prints the following:

```
"<User: xxxxxxx, objectId: xxxxxxx, localId: (null)>";
```

I'm surely mistaken but isn't `includeKey:` supposed to load the pointer object fully? Removing the `includeKey` yields the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is always represented like that whether it is included or not included. The only way (I know of) to find out if the pointer object has been downloaded is to print it. Try printing out `activity_object.user_object`.